# Fitting method in scickit'slearn Pipeline class

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

Let's say i have this python code:

```
from imblearn.pipeline import Pipeline


from sklearn.feature_selection import VarianceThreshold
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler 
from imblearn.over_sampling import RandomOverSampler
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA


selector = VarianceThreshold()
scaler = StandardScaler()
ros = RandomOverSampler()
pca = PCA()
clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_jobs=-1) 
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('selector', selector), ('scaler', scaler), ('sampler', ros), ('pca', pca), ('kNN', clf)])
pipe.fit(X_train,y_train)
preds = pipe.predict(X_test)
```

What this does is import 4 transformers and an estimator from scickit learn.Then it fit's these in the data and lastly it predicts.If i understand correctly fit method applies the 4 transformers to the data and the predict method makes the final estimation(in our case using kNN).My question is this:For scaler as well as pca the alterations that are done in the train data must be also applied in the test data.But in fit's parameters we don't give test and as a result the test data won't be altered.How does that make sense?Is there something i am missing?

Answer (score 1):

The model only learns the parameters from the training data and assumes that the test data will have similar patterns and transforms it accordingly. You cannot have a test data that is completely different from training data and expect good predictions, hence the same PCA and scaler models are also used on test dataset. If you fit a scaler on a smaller test dataset, the results might come out completely different than what the model is originally trained on.

Comment: So you don't change the test dataset at all?Because i read that whatever change is done using pca or normalization on the train set must be done n he test set too using the same parameters.

Comment: The test dataset is changed the same way as training dataset. I believe the pipeline does that on the test set too when you send it for predict.

Comment: That's what i thought too.Thank you